# Load all existent files (sprites) from Application.persistentDataPath? Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, load, text-files, sprite

In my game, you can take screenshots of the world, which are saved in `Application.persistentDataPath`. I want to make a gallery where you can then see all these screenshots. Because you need to write to the file, I can't use Resources folder or `Application.streamingAssetsPath`. I could read the files one sprite at a time, using the name, but that's not really practical. So how could I load all files and add them to an array or list? I basically need the equivalent of `Resources.LoadAll()`. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Just curious, why can't you use streamingAssets folder Andreea?

Comment: @Lotan When I was reading through the documentation of Streaming Assets, I found this: _On many platforms, the streaming assets folder location is read-only; you can not modify or write new files there at runtime. Use Application.persistentDataPath for a folder location that is writable._ And since I need to save the screenshots (as well as a few text files) created at runtime, my understanding is I cannot use StreamingAssets folder

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I was building a test cause you're right, the docs says that. BUT the test says the opposite, you can read and write, at least as a plain text in desktop. Screenshots can be stored and readed equally. Just use the folder like if it was another directory in C#.

Comment: @Lotan Oh really? That's great! I will try using StreamingAssets then. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lotan well the docs says **On many platforms** .. it doesn't say "on all". Yes it works for Desktop apps but beyond that you almost never want to/can write into StreamingAssets! You can use [`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html) also for loading texture from local file paths.

Comment: @Lotan It's platform dependant. On PC and Mac it might work. But we don't know the target platforms it may be built for either now or in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles(string,string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_) to return all filepaths in the persistentData folder e.g. by file extension (`"*.jpg"`)

Then you can use e.g. [`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html) also on local file paths and load assets from the persistent data path like

```c#
public Dictionary<string, Texture2D> textures = new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();

private void Start()
{
    var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath, "*.jpg");

    foreach(var fileName in fileNames)
    {
       StartCoroutine (LoadFile(fileName));
    }
}

private IEnumerator LoadFile(string filePath)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(filePath))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(uwr.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Get downloaded asset bundle
            var texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);

            // Something with the texture e.g.
            // store it to later access it by fileName
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            textures[fileName] = texture;
        }
    }
}
```